# .Net trying to load 'System.Net.WebProxy' from wrong assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, webproxy

My application in AspNetCore 3.1, runs locally without any issues with `dotnet run`. But when running the application in Docker i'm getting the following exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.WebProxy' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.\n   at[...]

This exception makes no sense, since `System.Net.WebProxy` isn't part of `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` and has nothing to do with the library. I'm guessing this isn't the root cause, but I can't find anything to point towards any other issue.

I've tried changing the dependency to use a different version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` and have tried different base images in my dockerfile. Reinstalled dotnet SDK etc. I'm at a total loss.

The following Method is where the application throws.

```
using MyApp.Model.Extensions;
using MyApp.Wrappers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
namespace My.App.Factories
{
    public class MyHttpClientFactory : IMyHttpClientFactory
    {

        public MyHttpClientFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
        }

        [...]

        private static HttpClientHandler GetClientHandler(string proxyAddress)
        {
            WebProxy proxy = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyAddress))
            {
                proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
            }

            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = proxy,
                UseProxy = proxy != null,
            };

            return httpClientHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

```
FROM openshift.repo.***.se/***/ubi-dotnet-31-***:latest AS builder
USER 0

ARG configuration=Release
ARG verbosity=normal

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish \
        --runtime linux-x64 \   
        --configuration ${configuration} \
        --output /usr/app/output \
        --verbosity ${verbosity} \
        /p:PublishTrimmed=true \
        /p:PublishSingleFile=false \ 
        ./src/My.App

FROM openshift.repo.***.se/***/ubi-dotnet-31-runtime-***:latest

WORKDIR /usr/app
 
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/output/ ./

USER 1001

EXPOSE 8080

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/app/My.App"]
```

Comment: Please show your Dockerfile. Have you tried using the base image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0`?

Comment: No i have not tried using a .NET 6 image for the .NET Core 3.1 solution. Included Dockerfile